# How to call a javascript function with PHP using onclick

Tags: javascript, php, onclick

I need to pass variables defined in PHP to a javascript function.
The JS function needs to be called with a button onclick event.

```
<button type="button" style="width: 70px;" class="btn btn-light btn-sm Center"
                  onclick="<?php  echo '<script>purchase('{$user}','{$painting1_Title}','200')</script>'?>">Purchase</button>
```

I have tried different connotations of single and double quotes but am getting parsing errors:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '',''
>   (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ProjectWebsite/Mainpage2.php on
>   line 303

So my question is how to call a javascript function with PHP inside a onclick event?

Comment: Remove the script tag from `onclick` attribute. Then fix the quotation, and your code should work.

Comment: You don't need those `script` tags and you need some correction with those quotes.
You can check this [link](https://ideone.com/S9wayn) for an idea.

Comment: You cannot call a JavaScript function from PHP. PHP composes the everything server-side, that result is then sent to the client (browser)  and the client then interprets the received data. But there is never a direct interaction between server-side  PHP and client-side JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want a result that looks something like this:

```
<button type="button" style="width: 70px;" class="btn btn-light btn-sm Center" onclick="purchase('user','painting_title','200')">Purchase</button>
```

You've some errors in your escaping and you should not use script tags, try this one:

```
<button type="button" style="width: 70px;" class="btn btn-light btn-sm Center"
                  onclick="<?php echo "purchase('" . $user . "','" . $painting1_Title . "','" . 200 . "')"; ?>">Purchase</button>
```

Comment: I get an 'unexpected token '<' with your example

Comment: Double-check implementation, it should work. Have a look here:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b45d116e8a511ab56367cbecb4651d3ce990ddb6

Answer (score 2):

You can always escape quotes inside of other quotes to prevent the nightmare of quote nesting.

`"This is how you would \"fix\" certain \"quotation issues\""`

My take is to use single quotes escaped inside of double quotes, even though usually single quotes work within double quotes.

`"This is how you would \'fix\' certain \'quotation issues\'"`